# Pascal, how to mark an integer into money value

Tags: delphi, integer, currency, pascal

How can I mark an integer into thousands and hundreds?
Just say I have an integer 12345678910, then I want to change it into a money value like 12.345.678.910.
I try the following code but it is not working.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
j,iPos,i, x, y : integer;
sTemp, original, hasil, data : string;
begin

 original := edit1.Text;
 sTemp := '';
  j := length(edit1.Text);
 i := 3;
   while i < j do
    begin
      insert('.',original, (j-i));
      edit1.Text := original;
      j := length(edit1.Text);
       for x := 1 to y do
        begin
         i := i + ( i + x );
        end;
    end;
   edit2.Text := original;
```

Comment: Use the [`Currency`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Currency) data type. Look at the [`StrToCurr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.StrToCurr) and [`FormatCurr()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.FormatCurr) functions.

Answer (score 5):

There is System.SysUtils.Format call in Delphi http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.SysUtils.Format.

This call understand `'m'` character as money specific formatter.
Try code like this:

```
Value := 12345678910;
FormattedStr := Format('Money = %m', [Value])
```

By default `Format` will use systemwide format settings, if you have to override default system settings, see official docs:

> The conversion is controlled by the CurrencyString, CurrencyFormat,
>   NegCurrFormat, ThousandSeparator, DecimalSeparator, and
>   CurrencyDecimals global variables or their equivalent in a
>   TFormatSettings data structure. If the format string contains a
>   precision specifier, it overrides the value given by the
>   CurrencyDecimals global variable or its TFormatSettings equivalent.

Comment: Note that there is an overload for Format that excepts a specific TFormatSettings.

Answer (score 1):

This function does what you specify:

```
function FormatThousandsSeparators(Value: Int64): string;
var
  Index: Integer;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Value);
  Index := Length(Result) - 3;
  while Index > 0 do
  begin
    Insert('.', Result, Index + 1);
    Dec(Index, 3);
  end;
end;
```

Note that your example `12345678910` does not fit into a 32 bit signed integer value which is why I used `Int64`.

This function does not handle negative values correctly. For instance, it returns `'-.999'` when passed `-999`. That can be dealt with like so:

```
function FormatThousandsSeparators(Value: Int64): string;
var
  Index: Integer;
  Negative: Boolean;
begin
  Negative := Value < 0;
  Result := IntToStr(Abs(Value));
  Index := Length(Result) - 3;
  while Index > 0 do
  begin
    Insert('.', Result, Index + 1);
    Dec(Index, 3);
  end;
  if Negative then
    Result := '-' + Result;
end;
```

Comment: Any reason for not using something like `CurrToStrF`?

Answer (score 0):

i know now, its so simple. just use

```
showMessage(formatFloat('#.###.00', strToFloat(original)));
```

but thanks Remy, you opened my mind.

Comment: If you use FPC or Delphi, have a look at the currency type. It is meant to carry currency.

Comment: As @MarcovandeVoort said: **rather use a type designed to carry currency, like the Currency type**. Floating point is not very well equipped to carry currencies. There may be round-off errors that **can cause unexpected values** to be produced. Not what you want when dealing with currency. You don't want amounts that may be a few cents/centimes/centavos etc. off.

Comment: FWIW, you could also use **my** [`BigDecimal`](http://rvelthuis.de/programs/bigdecimals.html) type, but that does not have a proper `FormatBigDecimal` function yet. Otherwise, it is ideal for currencies.